# Vertical divider does not show up

Tags: flutter

I am trying to recreate something like this photo below in Flutter

[image]

However I am stuck with the divider not showing up inside the main Row child and that is most likely because it does not have a height yet.
I have also tried to use a custom divider with `Container` yet nothing has showed till a height was given to the widget.

I would like to keep the widget dynamic and by that I mean I don't want to, if possible, restrict its height, the texts inside the widget are going to have `maxLines: 2` so they will not expand to infinity.

I know that using `IntrinsicHeight` would do the trick but it's well known that this widget is expensive.

Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly giving it a height or without using `IntrinsicHeight` ?

```dart
ColoredBox(
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      VerticalDivider(
        thickness: 4,
        color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary, // should appear in blue
      ),
      const Flexible(
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text('Title', maxLines: 2),
              Text('Description', maxLines: 2),
              Text('Made by', maxLines: 2),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

The main `Row` has the grey color and the `Column` has the green color and you can see the `VeticalDivider` is there but doesn't 'fully' appear unless height is restricted by any means whether specifically for it or the whole widget

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the vertical divider wigdet into `SizedBox` with required height like below:

```
  SizedBox(
    height: 60,
    child: VerticalDivider(
    thickness: 4,
    color: Colors.blue,
   ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you but I have mentioned that I am aware of this as a solution, however I want the divider to be as tall as the row (dynamic) which depends on the content of the three texts that could be somewhere between just two words and a maximum of two lines

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            width: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Task Type'),
            Text(
                'Task description here this one is really long and it goes over maybe? And goes to two lines.'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 3,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Due'),
                Text('Today,5.30 pm'),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  child: Text(
                    '1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 3,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Update',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Result Screen as per above image - [image]